# How to remove the range-key column in DynamoDb table without impacting the data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-migration

I need to remove the range-key in an existing Dynamo-DB table, without impacting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this on the existing table. You will need to do a data migration into a new table that is configured the way you want.

If the data migration can be done offline, you simply need to `Scan` all of the data out of the original table and `PutItem` it into the new table.

**Protip:** You can have multiple workers `Scan` a table in parallel if you have a large table. You simply need to assign each worker a `Segment`. Make sure your solution is robust enough to handle workers going down by starting a new worker and reassigning it the same `Segment` number.

Doing a live data migration isn't too bad either. You will need to create a DynamoDB Stream on the original table and attach a Lambda that essentially replays the changes onto the new table. The basic strategy is when an item is deleted, call `DeleteItem` on the new table and when an item is inserted or updated, call `PutItem` with the `NEW_IMAGE` on the new table. This will capture any live activity. Once that's set up, you need to copy over the data the same way you would in the offline case.

No matter what you do, you will be "impacting" the data. Removing the range key will fundamentally change the way the data is organized. Keep in mind it will also mean that you have a different uniqueness constraint on your data.

Comment: Streams could be a good option, I tried to migrate data  using pipeline and S3, but DynamoDb restrict this method to the table with same key set only as of the backed up copy. I concluded, that it is not data migration but data moving procedure between clouds.